# Significance level on real life

Tags: statistical-significance

Recently I was reading a problem for one-tailed test, a fragment in the resolution demanded my attention:

> "As noted in the preceding section, the level of significance, denoted
>   by ***α***, is the probability of making a Type I error by rejecting
>   ***Ho*** when the null hypothesis is true as an equality. The decision
>   maker must specify the level of significance. If **the cost of making** a
>   Type I error is high, a small value should be chosen for the level of
>   significance. If the cost is not high, a larger value is more
>   appropriate". *("Statistics for Business and Economics", Anderson,
>   11ed, page 357)*

We know the concept for level of significance, but the question is... based on what we assign a value for significance level? when a high value? when a small value? how do we determine the cost of making a certain type of error into business or research? In few words, how does the level of significance is worked on real life?

Answer (score 2):

Well, we have to use our brains and our substantive knowledge; often we will only be able to guess.

I am not a businessperson but it seems to me that at least some of the time in business, the costs of a type I vs. a type II error could be quantified, at least approximately. But how to do that would depend on the exact situation.

I would revise the quoted passage by saying the critical thing is cost of type I error vs. cost of type II error.